# Should the etale cohomology of a smooth projective variety (over rationals) be semi-simple; why?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, galois-representations, motives

$\DeclareMathOperator{\char}{char}\DeclareMathOperator{\gal}{Gal}$
Let $P$ be a smooth projective variety over a field $K$ (one may certainly assume that $K$ is perfect; the case $K=\mathbb{Q}$ already seems to be interesting enough). For some $\ell\neq \char K$, $n>0$, should the $n$-th $\mathbb Q_\ell$-adic Galois cohomology of $X_{K^{sep}}$ be semi-simple as a $\gal(K)$-representation? Certainly; no proof of this fact is known, so I would rather like to know whether it is related with some 'motivic' conjectures.

Some remarks:

1. For a finite $K$ one can consider the 'motivic' Frobenius; thus the conjecture follows from standard (motivic) ones. Yet this argument does not seem to work already for $K=\mathbb Q$.
2. It is certainly tempting to apply some polarizability argument. Yet my impression is that polarizability can only be applied to Hodge structures (in general); is this true?

Upd. It seems (see the comment of Ulrich) that 'my conjecture' is wrong for $K= \mathbb Q_\ell$; this settles my question. Yet I wonder where I can find the details for this example (when is the representation corresponding to an elliptic curve with multiplicative reduction  indecomposable).

Comment: I think the standard conjectures + the Tate conjecture imply this, because they imply that motives are semisimple, and galois representations from abelian varieties are motives.

Comment: Why does the semi-simplicity of motives imply the semi-simplicity of the corresponding representations? Representations could have subobjects that are not 'motivic'.

Comment: Mikhail, if you assume Tate, as Will suggested, then the subrepresentations would be motivic. Also, regarding 2, there is a conjecture that the image of $Gal(\matbb{Q})$ in $GL(H^i(X_{et}, \mathbb{Q}_\ell)$ is the $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$ points of the Mumford-Tate group of the Hodge structure on $H^i(X)$. If this were true then semisimplicity would follow from Hodge theory, but establishing this would perhaps be harder than establishing semisimplicity directly.

Comment: @Donu: This is not exactly true. If you consider the motive $M$ of rank 2 attached to an elliptic curve $E$ over a quadratic imaginary field $K$ with complex multiplication by $K$ defined over $K$, 
then $M_{\mathbb Q_l}$ will have sub-representations of dimension that are not motivic for half of the $l$'s, namely those which are split in $K$. Now your argument will work I think after extending the field of coefficients. Since semi-simplicity is invariant by extension of fields of the coefficients (which is not the case of course of irreducibility), your and Will's argument is saved. 

Comment: Dear Donu: the Tate conjecture certainly yields that a direct summand of a motivic representation is motivic. Yet why can you prove anything about arbitrary subrepresentations?

Comment: Dear Mikhail and Joel, I realize I was a bit hasty in my comment, but there is no way to edit it.

Comment: According to the Tate conjecture, l-adic realization gives an equivalence of categories from motives tensor $Q_l$ to the category of l-adic Galois representations generated by the cohomology of smooth projective algebraic varieties over $Q$. The standard conjectures imply the first is semisimple, hence also the second.

Comment: Semi-simplicity certainly does not hold for arbitrary $K$: for example, it does not hold for elliptic curves with multiplicative reduction over a $p$-adic field $K$

Comment: Dear ulrich: is the corresponding Galois representation necessarily indecomposable? 

Comment: Mikhail: it's almost always indecomposable in practice (you can usually check this by looking at the mod $p$ or mod $p^2$ torsion; already this usually is indecomposable). But I think that the general question about whether the extension is split is subtle. The extension class might be related to some sort of subtle invariant of the curve (e.g. maybe the log of some $L$-invariant?) so this might actually be some subtle question in transcendence theory!

Comment: PS ulrich's comment should be an answer, and if this doesn't solve the real question for you then perhaps you might want to edit to explain what the question now becomes.

Comment: PS Mikhail: here's a problem that is open (although some variant of it does follow from the standard conjectures). Take a modular form of weight $k\geq2$ and coefficient field $K$. Take a prime $p$ not dividing the level of $f$, and a prime $P$ of $K$ above $p$. Assume $a_p$, the $p$th Fourier coefficient of $f$, is a $P$-adic unit. Consider the Galois representation to $GL(2,K_P)$ attached to $f$ and restrict it to the abs Gal gp of $Q_p$. Is it true (there's computational evidence) that this rep is indecomposable iff $f$ has no CM? Funny 

Comment: oops I meant to continue Funny question, because input is local and output is global. If memory serves, Emerton proved that if you assume something slightly stronger, namely that $a_p$ is a $P$-adic unit for *all* $P$ above $p$, and that *all* the local reps are decomposable, then $f$ has CM, assuming the standard conjectures. One last thing: if $E$ is an elliptic curve over $Q_p$ with good ordinary reduction then the $p$-adic Tate module is in practice always indecomposable when $E$ has no CM, so there's another counterexample to the orig q, but I'm a bit unsure as to whether this is proved.

Comment: Mikhail: The Galois representation for elliptic curves with multiplicative reduction is easy to understand using the theory of Tate curves. One gets that the Tate module (which is equal to $H^1$ upto twist) in the the case of split multiplicative reduction is a (non-trivial) extension of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ by $\mathbb{Z}_p(1)$.  (See, for example, Silverman's book "Advanced Topics in the Arithemetic of Elliptic Curves" p. 452)

Comment: Minor correction: In my previous comment $p$ should be $l$ (an arbitrary prime) and the extension is non-split -- the image of the Galois group is non-abelian -- even with $\mathbb{Z}$ replaced by $\mathbb{Q}$. 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a base field finitely generated over the prime field, the Tate conjecture implies that the $l$-adic realization gives an equivalence from the category of pure motives tensor $\mathbb{Q}_l$ to the category of $l$-adic Galois representations generated by the cohomology of smooth projective algebraic varieties over the field. The standard conjectures imply that the category of pure motives  is semisimple, and hence also the category of Galois representations. (Actually, all you need for this is the Tate conjecture plus the conjecture that numerical equivalence and l-adic homological equivalence coincide, which are both in Tate's original Woods Hole article.)

For other base fields, the Galois representations need not be semisimple -- as ulrich explains in his comments.